# Cobertura Check & Validation

Tags: java, ant, code-coverage, cobertura

I see that Cobertura has a `<cobertura:check>` task that can be used to enforce coverage at build-time (if coverage metrics dip below a certain value, the build fails). The website shows examples with several different attributes that are available, but doesn't really give a description as to what they are or what they do:

- `branchrate`
- `linerate`
- `totalbranchrate`
- etc.

Also, what are the standard values for each of these attributes? I'm sure it will differ between projects, but there has to be *some* way for an organization to gauge what is acceptable and what isn't, and I'm wondering how to even arrive at that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [the documentation](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html) has changed since you asked the question, because I think your answer is right there now.

At the time that I'm writing this, the answers to your specific questions are:

- branchrate

> Specify the minimum acceptable branch coverage rate needed by each class. This should be an integer value between 0 and 100.

- linerate

> Specify the minimum acceptable line coverage rate needed by each class. This should be an integer value between 0 and 100.

- totalbranchrate

> Specify the minimum acceptable average branch coverage rate needed by the project as a whole. This should be an integer value between 0 and 100.
>
> If you do not specify branchrate, linerate, totalbranchrate or totallinerate, then Cobertura will use 50% for all of these values.

A bit of googling shows that most people agree that a "good" coverage number is somewhere from 75% - 95%.   I use %85 for new projects.  However, I think the metric that is the most useful in gauging whether you have enough test coverage is how comfortable your developers are in making and releasing changes to the code (assuming you have responsible developers who care about introducing bugs).  Remember, you can have 100% test coverage without a single assert in any test!

For legacy projects things are usually more complicated.  It's rare that you can get time to just focus on coverage alone, so most of the time you find out what your code coverage is, and then try to improve it over time.  My dream cobertura-check task would check if the coverage on any given line/method/class/package/project is the same as or better than the last build, and have separate thresholds for any code that is "new in this build."  Maybe [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) has something like that...